# Git: How to get the full name of object's hash?

Tags: git

I got short object hash from somewhere, for example, git diff:

```
diff --git a/Note1.md b/Note1.md
index 2b95b9f..b9596f0 100644
--- a/Note1.md
+++ b/Note1.md
@@ -1328,6 +1328,12 @@ variables.(starting with (@)
```

How can I get 40 byte length names of those short ID (2b95b9f and b9596f0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command:

`git show --pretty=%H <short-hash>`